# What is causing this little popup to move out of its container when using the scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a chat and when you hover on a profile picture it should give some details. Please take a look at this screenshot, in this screenshot it is displayed as it should be:
[image: screenshot1]

The problem is that when i scroll down, the popup box also goes down:
[image: screenshot 2]

My mouse is in the red circle, but the box is down after scrolling down.

What is causing this and how to fix it?

My code:

```
<?php
    if($lorr == "L") { $lorr = "R"; } else { $lorr = "L"; }
    if($lorr2 == "L") { $lorr2 = "R"; } else { $lorr2 = "L"; }
?> // Switch between left and right. Its called on every message
    <div class="Area">
        <div class="<?php echo $lorr; ?>">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <img class="chatimg" src="images/defava.png"/>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <?php echo $charrow['FIRSTNAME']; echo $charrow['LASTNAME']; ?><br/>
                    Level <?php echo $charrow['LEVEL']; ?><br/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="text <?php echo $lorr2; ?> text<?php echo $lorr2; ?>">
            <?php echo $chatrow['MESSAGE']; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    .Area .note
    {
      color:#9F6905;
      font-size:10px;
    }
    .R .tooltip
    {
      font-size:10px;
      position:absolute;
      background-color:#fff;
      padding:5px;
      border-radius:5px;
      border:2px solid #9F6905;
      margin-left:70px;
      margin-top:-70px;
      display:none;
      color:#545454;
    }
    .R .tooltip:before
    {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        height: 1px;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right-color: #9F6905;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: -17px;
    }
    .R:hover .tooltip
    {
      display:block;
    }

    .L .tooltip
    {
      font-size:10px;
      position:absolute;
      background-color:#fff;
      padding:5px;
      border-radius:5px;
      border:2px solid #9F6905;
      margin-left:70px;
      margin-top:-70px;
      display:none;  
      color:#545454;
    }
    .L .tooltip:before
    {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        height: 1px;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right-color: #9F6905;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: -17px;
    }
    .L:hover .tooltip
    {
      display:block;
    }
```

A link to a working example: codepen.io/anon/pen/ombZQM

Comment: What is `.R` and `.L`? Where exactly do you put your `.tooltip`? HTML or JS?

Comment: L and R is Left and Right. It decides whether the chat bubble is on the left or right screen. And switches between L and R for every chat message. .tooltip is called in the div class above.

Comment: Looks like you gave the tooltip `aboslute` position but didnt specify any of the `top`, `left`, `right`, or `bottom` in your css

Comment: But wouldnt that effect the position of where is it right now? The positions are dynamic and should just stop changing when using the scroll bar..

Comment: is it possible for you to include a non-PHP workable code snippet here so that we can inspect better from a working code?

Comment: Perhaps i should've done that right away. Will do next time.. Here you go: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ombZQM